# How to use the tags and classes in link_to helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here is the code for my link:

```
<%=link_to "My Stations", retailer_my_stations_path%>
```

I want to style the link like:

```
<a class="dropdown-collapse" href="#"><i class='icon-edit'></i>
    <span>My Stations</span>
</a>
```

How do I make Rails' `link_to` helper use the Icon `<i>` tag and the "My Stations" be inside the `<span>` tag like in the theme?

Comment: Do you actually want the href attribute to be `"#"`?  If not then please amend your question to have the desired html. If you do, then why include the reference to `retailer_my_stations_path`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass a block to [`link_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to):

```
<%= link_to retailer_my_stations_path, class: 'dropdown-collapse' do %>
  <i class='icon-edit'></i>
  <span>My Stations</span>
<% end %>
```

You can also create a helper method for this.

Answer (score 1):

`link_to` can optionally take a block. You can add all `html_options` in the `html_options` key.  I believe (but am not positive) that you reference the class directly.

I just use `html_options` because it always works:

```
 <% link_to(link_to "My Stations", retailer_my_stations_path, html_options: {class: "drop-down-collapse"} ) do %>
     other tags i.e. span
 <% end %>
```